# ActionBar colour wont change

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have this style definition

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generated with http://android-holo-colors.com -->
<resources>

    <style name="FUTheme" parent="@style/_FUTheme"/>

    <style name="_FUTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        ....

    </style>
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">#7C2582</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@drawable/futheme_list_selector_holo_light</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And in my manifest

```
android:theme="@style/FUTheme"
```

What have I done wrong? I'm using the AppCompat library

Comment: I'm having this exact issue. I wonder if there is anything AppCompat lib could be doing.

Comment: The problem I had was I didn't have the colour in my values-v11 style.xml. Put the colour in each style file you have and try that, worked for me!

Comment: follow this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22878829/1675469

Answer (score -2):

Put it to onCreate void in Activity.

```
  ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
  bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new.     ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0000ff")));
```